# geoserver wrong tile generation on leaflet

Tags: geoserver, leaflet, tiles

I am creating world map with bathymetry using Geoserver 2.5.1 and leaflet.
It works perfactly upto certain zoom level. but after that i get few tiles drawn in wrong color as shows in images. Does anyone have any idea why geoserver behaving like it or any direction to fix it?

As i zoom in more on the map tiles are missing colors as shown below.

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: we need to know how you styled the layer in GeoServer and what the request for the "wrong" tiles looks like.

Comment: looks like they are crossing the 180 degrees. What projection are you using for the data?

Comment: @DevdattaTengshe - yes they are on 180 line. i am using web mecator - ESPG 3857